# adding text in text view on clicking submit button android2.2

Tags: android, dynamic, textview

what i trying to do is i am adding some text in the edit text and
i want that on submit button  it get added in text view provided below...therefore,everytime i add d text on submit it should get appended in that text view
but the problem is its getting overwritten

here s d code:

```
      // submit button

      final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Submit);
      button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {

      // Perform action on click

      EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EnterText);
      TextView history=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.history);

      history.setText(et.getText().toString());
      }

      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
history.setText(et.getText().toString());
```

To

```
history.setText(history.getText() + et.getText().toString());
```

This should append the new Text.

Comment: history.setText(history.getText() + "\n" + et.getText().toString());

Comment: one more thing i have one doubt :
i'm writing  some text in edit text (the character limit is set to 140)
and i want to display the character count in d edit text in a text view in decreasing order


 for example: if the text in the edit text is **hello**
the count in the text view should be **135**(140-5)
can u help?

Comment: Look at this Page:
http://www.andreabaccega.com/blog/2010/10/09/onchange-event-on-edittext-in-android/

You have to implement an onTextChangeListener.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
history.setText(history.getText() + "\n" + et.getText().toString());
```

Comment: i have one doubt :
i'm writing  some text in edit text (the character limit is set to 140)
and i want to display the character count in d edit text in a text view in decreasing order


 for example: if the text in the edit text is **hello**
the count in the text view should be **135**(140-5)

can u help me with this thing?

Comment: @rav that you have put into the keychange event every time get the string length and deducted from the specified value

Answer (score 0):

try..

> history.setText(history.getText() + et.getText().toString());

Comment: add "\n" to put the new text on the new line

Answer (score 0):

use this to append the text in next line :

```
history.setText(history.getText() +"\n" +et.getText().toString());
```

Comment: i have one doubt :
i'm writing  some text in edit text (the character limit is set to 140)
and i want to display the character count in d edit text in a text view in decreasing order


 for example: if the text in the edit text is **hello**
the count in the text view should be **135**(140-5)

can u help me with this thing?